# Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null in JSF form

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I tested this source code:

***Bean:***

```
private NewAccountObj na;

public class NewAccountObj {

    private int userid;
        ............

    public NewAccountObj(int userid.............) {

        this.userid = userid;
            ............
        }

        public int getUserid() {
            return userid;
        }

        ...............

    }

    // Getters 
    public NewAccountObj getDataList() {        
        return na;
    }
```

***JSF Page:***

```
<h:panelGrid columns="2">
    <h:panelGroup>User ID</h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup>
        <h:inputText id="userid" value="#{bean.dataList['userid']}">                    
        </h:inputText>
    </h:panelGroup>
......................
</h:panelGrid>
```

When I submit the form I get `Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null`.
Can you help me to find the problem? Maye this is not the proper way to access Java object in `h:panelGrid`?

***PS:***

I get this error message in Glassfish log:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /NewAccount.xhtml @38,126 value="#{NewAccountController.dataList['userid']}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
```

Comment: The exception basically tells that `#{bean}` is `null`. Show how you configured it.

Comment: I found the problem! I need to initialize the Java object and then to use it into the JSF page. I added this: `na = new NewAccountObj(0, 0, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);` into the constructor. By the way this is very ugly solution. Is there any other elegant solution to initialize empty object in Java?

Comment: Erm, create a default c'tor?

Comment: Something like this `NewAccountObj na = new NewAccountObj();`? Netbeans gives me error that I need to pass arguments.

Comment: As said.. create a default c'tor.

Comment: @BalusC, how he can call bean getter method in inputText like this #{bean.dataList['userid']} ?

Comment: you should set the userId to a property in managed bean #{bean.userId}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the above code, the NewAccountObj is null. So when the `getDataList()` is called, it returns null. Then it will to call `null.getUserId()`.

`na` needs to be initialized. I see in your comment that you have a very long constructor, you should create another one with no arguments (or the minimum required for the object to work).

```
private NewAccountObj na;

    public class NewAccountObj {

        private int userid;
        ............

        public NewAccountObj() {
            new New AccountObj(0,0,...........);
        }

        public NewAccountObj(int userid.............) {

            this.userid = userid;
            ............

        }

        public int getUserid() {
            return userid;
        }

        ...............

    }

    // Getters 
    public NewAccountObj getDataList() {        
        return na;
    }
```

And change the datalist getter like this:

```
public NewAccountObj getDataList() {
    if(na == null){
        na = new NewAccountObj();
    }
    return na;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
ADD set property method

public int setUserid(int userid) {
           this.userid =userid ;
        }
```

Comment: A missing setter wouldn't result in this kind of exception. It's totally beyond me why this answer is upvoted.