# Bean null after sign up user?

Tags: jsf, exception, jsf-2

I have a bean `UserControl` with `SessionScope`, after the user `register` at the system, he/she would try to log in on the system, right ?

The same bean is used for it, but after the try log in once (with a wrong passwod for instance) on the second try, appears an exception that my bean is `null`, why ?

I use the same `composition` at `register form` and `login form`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<ui:composition
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

    E-Mail:<h:message id="m_email" for="email" styleClass="red" /><br/>
    <h:inputText id="email" value="#{userC.user.email}" maxlength="45" validatorMessage="e-mail inválido" >
        <f:validateLength minimum="6" maximum="45" />
        <f:ajax event="blur" render="m_email" />
    </h:inputText>
    <br/>
</ui:composition>
```

At the first time work but on the second, don't.
Given me this exception:

```
/resources/jsf/composition/body/user/form/email.xhtml @9,108 value="#{userC.user.email}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
```

This is my bean, `UserControl`:

```
@ManagedBean(name="userC")
@SessionScoped
public class UserControl  implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7708365499838642904L;

    @EJB UserEAO userEAO;
    @EJB AddressEAO addressEAO;

    private User user;

    private Message message;

    /*
     * Variable
     */
    private boolean logged;

    public UserControl(){
        user = new User();
        user.setAddressCity(new AddressCity());
        user.setAddressState(new AddressState());
        user.setAddressCountry(new AddressCountry());

        logged = false;
    }
  .. methods
}
```

Is wrong initiate my `objects` in the `constructor` ?

**update**
Full code of `UserControl`:

```
package com.hi.mvc.controller;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.ExternalContext;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;

import com.hi.mvc.eao.AddressEAO;
import com.hi.mvc.eao.UserEAO;
import com.hi.mvc.model.AddressCity;
import com.hi.mvc.model.AddressCountry;
import com.hi.mvc.model.AddressState;
import com.hi.mvc.model.User;
import com.hi.utility.Crypto;
import com.hi.utility.Email;
import com.hi.utility.Message;

@ManagedBean(name="userC")
@SessionScoped
public class UserControl  implements Serializable{
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 7708365499838642904L;

        @EJB UserEAO userEAO;
        @EJB AddressEAO addressEAO;

        private User user;

        private Message message;

        /*
         * Variable
         */
        private boolean logged;

        public UserControl(){
                user = new User();
                user.setAddressCity(new AddressCity());
                user.setAddressState(new AddressState());
                user.setAddressCountry(new AddressCountry());

                logged = false;
        }

        /*
         * CRUD
         */
        public String register(){
                if (userEAO.find(user.getEmail()) == null){
                        defineUser();

                        message = userEAO.create(user);
                        //sending user email confirmation
                        if (message.getCode() == 0) {
                                message = new Message(1);
                                message.setEmail(user.getEmail());

                                sendConfirmationEmail(user);
                                return "/pages/system/message.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
                        }else
                                //user already registered and trying to register again
                                message = new Message(-1002);
                }

                addMessage();
                return null;
        }

        public String update() {
                message = userEAO.update(user);

                this.addMessage();
                return null;
        }

        public String delete(){
                message = userEAO.delete(user);
                if (message.getCode() >= 0)
                try {
                        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
                        ec.invalidateSession();

                        message = new Message(3001);
                        addMessage();

                        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/pages/system/message.xhtml");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                addMessage();
                return null;
        }

        /*
         *  Log in/off
         */
        public String login(){
                String password = user.getPassword();
                user = userEAO.find(user.getEmail());
                // if user was found
                if ( user != null ){
                        if ( user.getEmailConfirmed()){
                                // with facebook registration, password is empty, so we avoid login empty and check the password
                                if ( !user.getPassword().isEmpty() && Crypto.check(password, user.getPassword())){
                                        //user = addressEAO.findByUser(user.getId());
                                        logged = true;

                                        return "/index.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
                                }else
                                        message = new Message(-2000);

                        }else
                                message = new Message(-1003);
                }else
                        message = new Message(-2000);

                addMessage();
                return null;
        }

        public void logout(){
                try {
                        ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
                        ec.invalidateSession();
                        ec.redirect(ec.getRequestContextPath() + "/index.xhtml");
                } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }

        /*
         * Functions
         */
        public void defineUser(){
                encryptPassword(user);
                user.setMemberSince(new Date());
                user.setAcceptanceRate(0);
                user.setResponseRate(0);

                // user do not confirm email yet
                user.setEmailConfirmed(false);

                // set address to be empty
                user.getAddressCity().setCity(" ");
                user.getAddressState().setState(" ");
                user.getAddressCountry().setCode(" ");
                defineAddress();
        }

        public void defineAddress(){
                AddressCity addressCity = addressEAO.findCity(user.getAddressCity().getCity());
                if (addressCity == null){
                        addressCity = new AddressCity();
                        addressCity.setCity(user.getAddressCity().getCity());
                        addressEAO.createCity(addressCity);
                }
                user.setAddressCity(addressCity);

                AddressState addressState = addressEAO.findState(user.getAddressState().getState());
                if (addressState == null){
                        addressState = new AddressState();
                        addressState.setState(user.getAddressState().getState());
                        addressEAO.createState(addressState);
                }
                user.setAddressState(addressState);

                AddressCountry addressCountry = addressEAO.findCountry(user.getAddressCountry().getCode());
                if (addressCountry == null){
                        addressCountry = new AddressCountry();
                        addressCountry.setCode(user.getAddressCountry().getCountry());
                        addressEAO.createCountry(addressCountry);
                }
                user.setAddressCountry(addressCountry);
        }

        /*
         * Date
         */
        public Date convertDate(String date){
                try {
                        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");  
                        return (Date)formatter.parse(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return null;
        }

        /*
         * E-Mail
         */
        public void sendConfirmationEmail(User u){
                Email email = new Email();
                email.setUser(u);
                email.setSubject("Hotel Informal - Por favor, confirme seu endereço de email");
                email.simpleEmail();
        }

        public void sendWelcomeEmail(User u){
                Email email = new Email();
                email.setUser(u);
                email.setSubject("Hotel Informal - Olá, seja bem-vindo(a)");
                email.simpleEmail();
        }

        public String resendEmailConfirmation(){
                sendConfirmationEmail(user);
                message = new Message(2);
                message.setEmail(this.user.getEmail());

                return "/pages/system/message.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }

        /*
         * Password
         */
        public void encryptPassword(User u) {
                if (u.getPassword() != null){
                        u.setPassword(Crypto.encrypt(u.getPassword()));
                }
        }

        public String changePassword(){
                encryptPassword(user);
                message = userEAO.update(user);
                if (message.getCode() >= 0)
                        message = new Message(2002);

                addMessage();
                return null;
        }

        public Message checkPassword(User user) {
                if (user == null)
                        return new Message(-3000);

                if (Crypto.check(user.getPassword(), user.getPassword())) {
                        return new Message(1);
                } else
                        return new Message(-2000);
        }

        public String forgotPassword(){
                user = userEAO.find(user.getEmail());
                if (user != null){
                        Email email = new Email();
                        email.setUser(user);
                        email.setSubject("Hotel Informal - Redefinir senha");
                        email.simpleEmail();

                        message = new Message(6);
                        message.setEmail(user.getEmail());
                }else
                        message = new Message(-1004);

                addMessage();
                return "/pages/system/message.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }       

        public String resetPassword(){
                encryptPassword(user);
                userEAO.update(user);

                Email email = new Email();
                email.setUser(user);
                email.setSubject("Hotel Informal - Senha redefinida");
                email.simpleEmail();

                message.setEmail(user.getEmail());
                message = new Message(2001);

                addMessage();
                return "/pages/system/message.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
        }

        private void addMessage(){
                FacesMessage fMessage = new FacesMessage(message.getMessage());
                FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, fMessage);
        }

        // get's & set's

        public Message getMessage() {
                return message;
        }

        public void setMessage(Message message) {
                this.message = message;
        }

        public User getUser() {
                return user;
        }

        public void setUser(User user) {
                this.user = user;
        }

        public boolean isLogged() {
                return logged;
        }

        public void setLogged(boolean logged) {
                this.logged = logged;
        }


}
```

Comment: Not sure if this is the problem but I think you have a common misconception about how persistent scoped managed beans work.  After a request response cycle, the bean object itself is destroyed, just the model values are persisted. At the second response, the bean object is actually *recreated* and THEN the previous serialized model values are applied to the new bean instance.  You can use the `@PostConstruct` annotation on an initialization method to do a null check on user, and if it is null then create a new User object and that might fix your problem.

Comment: @maple_shaft, so if I understand correctly, I always have to implement the `constructor` and the `@PostConstruct` ?

Comment: I can't see all of your code so I can't tell you what you have to do, I am just informing you about SessionScoped managed beans work.  The constructor will be called on every client request. The PostConstruct is a more appropriate way to initialize a bean though.  I was also suggesting that you might want to do null checks as well because the last saved bean values don't get set until AFTER the constructor and AFTER PostConstruct.

Comment: In addition to maple_shaft's recommendation, "null resolved to null" indicates that the context is unable to name the offending component. What package is `@SessionScoped` from?

Comment: @kolossus, `import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;`. Also I update my post, with whole bean, could you please take a look ?

Comment: @maple_shaft, I update my post, showing you how I deal with my bean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the suggestions of `maple_shaft` and `kolossun` wasn't enough to solve my problem, but following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858154/target-unreachable-null-returned-null-in-jsf-form) suggestion, to check if the `user` is `null` in the `public User getUser()` method was.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    if (user == null){
        user = new User();
        logged = false;
    }

    if (user != null && user.getAddressCity() == null)
        user.setAddressCity(new AddressCity());

    if (user != null && user.getAddressState() == null)
        user.setAddressState(new AddressState());

    if (user != null && user.getAddressCountry() == null)
        user.setAddressCountry(new AddressCountry());
}
```

And :

```
public User getUser() {
    init();
    return user;
}
```

This way I ensure that the object `user` and the others classes are always initialized.
Still I don't understand why doing the `null` check in `@PostConstruct` wasn't enough, it keeps given me the same error.